# Vue-infinite-loading reactivity

Tags: vue-reactivity, vue-infinite-loading

I'm using **vue-infinite-loading** on **Nuxt** and works great.
The problem is that if one of the items is modified, it won't be refreshed on the screen until reloading (for instance, changing the identifier). Is there any way or consideration to make it reactive ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I discover that using splice to remove/insert an item is not reactive, assigning new values to the array item did work.